# Wicket FullCalendar and Bootstrap what version of each

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar, wicket

I am trying to use the latest Wicket FullCalendar 2.3 code but I am getting a javascript error on startup.

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function CalendarPage?0:139 
(anonymous function)jquery.min.js:2 
n.Callbacks.jjquery.min.js:2 
n.Callbacks.k.fireWithjquery.min.js:2 
n.extend.readyjquery.min.js:2
```

I am using the jquery that is sent with the fullcalendar code with the latest version of bootstrap for additional UI components 3.3.2.

I'm running into version errors. Bootstrap wants a jquery 1.9 or higher but the fullcalendar came with 1.8. I have switched back and forth between them but the error doesn't resolve itself.

Is there a compatible version out there?

```
Config config = new Config();
        config.setSelectable(true);
        config.setSelectHelper(false);

        EventSource reservations = new EventSource();
        reservations.setTitle("Reservations");
        reservations
                .setEventsProvider(new RandomEventsProvider("Reservation "));
        reservations.setEditable(true);
        reservations.setBackgroundColor("#63BA68");
        reservations.setBorderColor("#63BA68");
        config.add(reservations);

        EventSource downtimes = new EventSource();
        downtimes.setTitle("Maintenance");
        downtimes.setBackgroundColor("#B1ADAC");
        downtimes.setBorderColor("#B1ADAC");
        downtimes.setEventsProvider(new RandomEventsProvider("Maintenance "));
        config.add(downtimes);

        EventSource other = new EventSource();
        other.setTitle("Other Reservations");
        other.setBackgroundColor("#E6CC7F");
        other.setBorderColor("#E6CC7F");
        other.setEventsProvider(new RandomEventsProvider("Other Reservations "));
        config.add(other);

        config.getHeader().setLeft("prev,next today");
        config.getHeader().setCenter("title");
        config.getHeader().setRight("month,agendaWeek");

        config.setLoading("function(bool) { if (bool) $(\"#loading\").show(); else $(\"#loading\").hide(); }");

        config.setWeekends(false);
        config.setMinTime(new LocalTime(6, 30));
        config.setMaxTime(new LocalTime(17, 30));
        config.setAllDaySlot(false);
        FullCalendar calendar = new FullCalendar("cal", config) {

            @Override
            protected void onViewDisplayed(View view, CalendarResponse response) {

                info("View displayed. viewType: " + view.getType().name()
                        + ", start: " + view.getStart() + ", end: "
                        + view.getEnd());
                response.getTarget().add(feedback);
            }
        };
        calendar.setMarkupId("calendar");
        add(calendar);
        add(new EventSourceSelector("selector", calendar));
```

Comment: Is this happening at page load, or only when you try to use the library in a function? If we could see the code that is causing this, we could possibly help you better.

Comment: Its on page load. I haven't added anything custom yet. Just trying to get the example code to work. This is straight out of what is delivered as a working example with the latest version

Comment: Note that the onViewDisplayed doesn't seem to be firing... there is nothing printed to the logs

Comment: Get at least jQuery 1.11, if not the latest of 2. (The only reason to not upgrade to 2 is to support IE8, but that shouldn't be an issue anymore now that XP has been deprecated).